# Node component hasn't method set with socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, peerjs

I'm just configuring peerjs with socket.io 
following [this thread](http://stephantabor.com/2015/07/11/express-peerjs-and-socket-io/), the communication between the components `connect` and `disconect` from the server are working good, but when I'm starting the socket.io integration, the next error occurs:

```
app.set('port', port);
    ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'set'
 This is most likely a problem with the myapp package,
```

And my server configuration is:

```
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 9000));  
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client'));

var peerOptions = {  
  debug: true
};

app.use('/api', expressPeerServer(server, peerOptions));

io.on('connection', function(socket){  
  socket.emit('env', process.env.NODE_ENV, app.get('port'));
});

server.listen(app.get('port'), function(){  
  console.log('Server running at localhost: ', app.get('port'));
});
```

**App.js**

```
var express = require('express');  
var app = express();  
var server = require('http').Server(app);  
var io = require('socket.io')(server);  
var expressPeerServer = require('peer').ExpressPeerServer;

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 9000));  
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client'));

var peerOptions = {  
  debug: true
};

app.use('/api', expressPeerServer(server, peerOptions));

io.on('connection', function(socket){  
  socket.emit('env', process.env.NODE_ENV, app.get('port'));
});

server.listen(app.get('port'), function(){  
  console.log('Server running at localhost: ', app.get('port'));
});
```

Exist an error releated with my server configuration?

Comment: Where is `app` assigned?

Comment: `var app = express();`   @mscdex

Comment: Are you sure you're not reassigning it somewhere in between? Can you provide more complete code? `var app = express();` should work just fine.

Comment: The code is updated now. @mscdex

Comment: What Express version does `npm ls` show?

Comment: The express version is: `~4.13.1` in the `package.json` and uisng `npm ls` is the `4.13.3` @mscdex

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that code. What node version are you using out of curiousity?

Comment: I have the same exact issue. Express 4.13.1 with node v0.10.25